# Display blob content using Eclipse database explorer

Tags: sql, database, eclipse

I'm connected, using Eclipse database development view (standard of Eclipse Indigo), to an Oracle DB in which, for a particular record (that I already know), I want to view one column content in "text" form (although the column contains BLOB data).

When I simply do a

```
select MYBLOBCOLUMN from MYTABLE where ID='myid'
```

SQL results view only show an execution log, but no data. So, how can I see that BLOB content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BLOB datatype was invented in order to be able to transfer "custom" objects from one database to another. The Database itself has no idea how to interpret and display the stored data in the blob field.

It can be an image, application, video, audio or anything else. If you have stored normal text in a blob field your database program has no idea that it is regular text.

If you store text in a database, you better use (n)varchar or memo data type.

Comment: Well, I know that, but I was thinking that, like in binary compatible text editors (notepad++ and the such) there could be a way in Eclipse to display that binary stream as text.

Comment: ah ok, understand what you mean, i actually work with ms sql server express, and i believe it indeed displays images as character strings.. I wouldnt know how to set eclipse to do that. sorry